# How to program ASP.NET web.config FederationMetadata appSettings keys?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, ws-federation

Is there a way to programmatically create the "ida" keys in 
below?

```
<add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="http://xxxxx/FederationMetadata" />
<add key="ida:Issuer" value="http://xxxxxx/Issuer" />
<add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
```

Answer (score -1):

[Configuration.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8693ks1(v=vs.110).aspx) is a writable collection so you can certainly do this .  These keys, however are only needed for the "identity and access" visual studio plugin.  AFAIK they are never used at runtime so there is little use in creating them.